# How to put comma in a mathematical expression like 23214+3157x56 as 23,214+3,157x56?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
String my_expr=editText.getText().toString();
Long val = Long.parseLong(my_expr);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String formattedString = formatter.format(val);
editText1.setText(formattedString);
```

I've taken the whole expression(my_expr) as a single string value.I applied textWatcher but it doesn't work after operators.

Comment: You can break the string into tokens (separated by math operators), then apply the decimal formatting to each token and then join all formatted tokens accordingly with respective math operators. Stack implementation can be useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If `my_expr` is the full expression, i.e. something like `"23214+3157x56"`, then this won't work since `Long.parse(my_expr)` expects a single number. You  need to split the expression string into each number first.

```
// 23214+3157x56
String my_expr = editText.getText().toString();

// [23214, +, 3157, x, 56]
String[] splitted = my_expr.split("((?<=[-+x/])|(?=[-+x/]))");

StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
for (String word : splitted) {
  try {
    double num = Double.parseDouble(word);
    formatted.append(formatter.format(num));
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    formatted.append(word);
  }
}

// formatted.toString() -> "23,214+3,157x56"
editText1.setText(formatted.toString(), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
```

The regular expression used to create split should contain all characters you're using as operators. If you have operators that use parentheses or more than one character, this approach won't work and you'll have to change the regular expression used for splitting or create your own parser.

Also I recommend using `Double.parseDouble(String)` over parsing the expression into longs.

Comment: I've taken the input one by one in that editText. This code isn't working dear.

Comment: @Vekash Is your issue with parsing the expression or actually setting the formatted text? Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Comment: its about parsing.

Comment: Does your expression match what I'm expecting? This works for me so I need more details about what is being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Here a second approach:

```
include java.text.*;

String expr="23214+3157x56"
String[] oper=expr.split ("[0-9]+") 
String[] ls = expr.split ("[-+x/]");
List<String> sl = new ArrayList <> ();

for (String s : ls) { 
    Long l = Long.parseLong (s); 
    sl.add (String.format ("%1$,d", l));
} 

String res = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < sl.size (); ++i) {
   res += oper[i] + sl.get(i); 
}
```

jshell:
-> res
|  Variable res of type String has value "23.214+ 3.157x    56"